# Cannot make a href link to work

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, href

I am trying to include pagination on a site and I encountered this problem.
I have the following line, but instead of `index.php` I must put `index.php?view_vehicles`.

This is the line:

```
echo "<a href='index.php?page=$next'>Next</a> ";
```

It's the first time I encounter this issue and I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: *"I must put index.php?view_vehicles"* and you're using `index.php?page`, something I don't get here.

Comment: Is your `$next` variable set? also `index.php?view_vehicles` != `?page=$next`. missing page parameter?

Comment: It must be something like this: <a href='index.php?view_vehicles?page=$next'>Next</a> but it's now working this way.

Comment: Which is wrong.

Comment: First of all, we don't know what you are trying to say. Explain properly, what is being passed, where should it get redirected?

Comment: you need an `&` for additional GET parameters, not 2 `?`'s

Comment: `<a href='index.php?view_vehicles&page=$next'>Next</a>` there, that's what you want here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, now it works!

Comment: @AndreiCT you're welcome. I posted my answer below that you can mark off as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

> *"It must be something like this: `<a href='index.php?view_vehicles?page=$next'>Next</a>` but it's now working this way. – AndreiCT*

[As I stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149505/cannot-make-a-href-link-to-work#comment69501603_41149505), additional GET parameters require `&` after the first parameter, not 2x `?`.

```
<a href='index.php?view_vehicles&page=$next'>Next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the variable $next in the string you're echoing:

```
echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$next."'>Next</>";
```